# Navigator package error: ‘I can't find file `yax' \input yax’

Tags: errors, embedding

With TeXLive 2013, under Linux Mint KDE 16, when I try to embed a file with the `navigator` package, I get the following errors pointing to navigator.tex and the source won't compile:

```
line 14: I can't find file `yax' \input yax
line 14: Emergency stop \input yax
```

I can also reproduce the error with the following minimal working example (I can replace the file name with a concrete name of any file, whether it exists or not, but the result is still the same):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{navigator}
\embeddedfile{sourcecode}{\jobname.tex}

\begin{document}
The document
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This sounds like a version conflict or similar. Could you edit in your `.log` file?

Comment: Do you have `yax.tex` installed on your system?  What does `kpsewhich yax.tex` say?

Comment: Thank you, @jon, for mentioning `yax.tex`! I checked it by the `tlmgr install yax` command and it got installed right away, so it was missing, indeed. After that, I got another error message but this time about `texapi` missing. So I installed the `texapi` package, too, and I could successfully compile the source with the file embedded.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because missing files error simply fixed by updating the distribution to install the needed packages.